# Creating dump file with use command

Tags: mysql, backup, mysqldump

I am taking backup of 2 tables from different schema.
I need to create the "use dbname" statement at the beginning of each table.

```
mysqldump --databases company --tables loadme --databases new_company --tables new_load

use company
...
usual loadme dump
...

use new_company
...
usual new_load dump
...
```

This does not seem to be possible with mysqldump command.

Answer (score 2):

The [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html) utility can dump the following ways from a MySQL Instance:

- All Databases
- One Whole Database
- Part of a Database

  - It is possible to mysqldump a space-separated list of tables from one Database
- One Whole Table

  - It is not possible to mysqldump a table from one Database and a table from another
- Part of a Table Using `--where` Option
- Stored Procedures
- Schema Only
- Data Only

You cannot mysqldump two tables from two different schema. You must script the tables you want dumps one at a time.

Here is a script to dump every table from a MySQL Instance into separate files

```
MYSQL_USER=root
MYSQL_PASS=rootpass
MYSQL_CONN="-u${MYSQL_USER} -p${MYSQL_PASS}"
SQL="SELECT CONCAT(table_schema,'.',table_name) FROM information_schema.tables"
SQL="${SQL} WHERE table_schema NOT IN ('information_schema','mysql')"
mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} -ANe"${SQL}" > /tmp/ListOfTables.txt
COMMIT_COUNT=0
COMMIT_LIMIT=10
for DBTB in `cat /tmp/ListOfTables.txt`
do
    DB=`echo ${DBTB} | sed 's/\./ /g' | awk '{print $1}'`
    TB=`echo ${DBTB} | sed 's/\./ /g' | awk '{print $2}'`
    mysqldump ${MYSQL_CONN} --hex-blob --triggers ${DB} ${TB} > ${DB}_${TB}.sql &
    (( COMMIT_COUNT++ ))
    if [ ${COMMIT_COUNT} -eq ${COMMIT_LIMIT} ]
    then
        COMMIT_COUNT=0
        wait
    fi
done
if [ ${COMMIT_COUNT} -gt 0 ]
then
    wait
fi
```

In your case, you can create the /tmp/ListOfTables.txt file manually. In order to inject `use dbname`, just create the dump file with the `use dbname` as the first line. Then, append the output of mysqldump to it. Keep in mind that each table is described as dbname.tablename:

```
rm -f /tmp/ListOfTables.txt
echo "company.loadme" >> /tmp/ListOfTables.txt
echo "new_company.newload" >> /tmp/ListOfTables.txt
MYSQL_USER=root
MYSQL_PASS=rootpass
MYSQL_CONN="-u${MYSQL_USER} -p${MYSQL_PASS}"
COMMIT_COUNT=0
COMMIT_LIMIT=10
for DBTB in `cat /tmp/ListOfTables.txt`
do
    DB=`echo ${DBTB} | sed 's/\./ /g' | awk '{print $1}'`
    TB=`echo ${DBTB} | sed 's/\./ /g' | awk '{print $2}'`
    echo "use ${DB}" > ${DB}_${TB}.sql
    mysqldump ${MYSQL_CONN} --hex-blob --triggers ${DB} ${TB} >> ${DB}_${TB}.sql &
    (( COMMIT_COUNT++ ))
    if [ ${COMMIT_COUNT} -eq ${COMMIT_LIMIT} ]
    then
        COMMIT_COUNT=0
        wait
    fi
done
if [ ${COMMIT_COUNT} -gt 0 ]
then
    wait
fi
```

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: I will like to avoid script. Is it possible to dump 1 table from 1 database but with "use schema" at the top?

Comment: mysqldump was not designed to do that

Comment: I did update my answer about 42 minutes ago to append mysqldump to `use dbname`.